# Python: find a string between 2 strings in text

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a text like this

```
s = """
...

(1) Literature

1. a.
2. b.
3. c.

...
"""
```

I want to cut Literature section but I have some problem with detection.

I use here

```
re.search("(1) Literature\n\n(.*).\n\n", s).group(1)
```

but `search` return None.

Desire output is

```
(1) Literature

1. a.
2. b.
3. c.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Probably you need `r'\(1\)\s+Literature\s+((?:.+\n)+)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match `(1) Literature` and 2 newlines, and then capture all lines that start with digits followed by a dot.

```
\(1\) Literature\n\n((?:\d+\..*(?:\n|$))+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(1\) Literature\n\n` Match (1) Literature and 2 newlines
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\d+\..*(?:\n|$)` Match 1+ digits and a dot followed by either a newline or end of string
  - `)+` Close non capture group and repeat it 1 or more times to match all the lines
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KVgchX/1)

---

Another option is to capture all following lines that do not start with `(` digits `)` using a negative lookahead, and then trim the leading and trailing whitespaces.

```
\(1\) Literature((?:\n(?!\(\d+\)).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xTXdmb/1)

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses have a special meaning in regex. They are used to group matches.

`(1)` - Capture 1 as the first capturing group.

Since the string has parentheses in it, the match is not successful. And `.*` capturing end with line end.

[Check Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BP6N27/1)

Based on your regex, I assumed you wanted to capture the line with the word `Literature`, 5 lines below it. Here is a regex to do so.

```
\(1\) Literature(.*\n){5}
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uc52dm/1)

Note the scape characters used on parentheses around `1`.

**EDIT**

Based on zr0gravity7's comment, I came up with this regex to capture the middle section on the string.

```
\(1\)\sLiterature\n+((.*\n){3})
```

This regex will capture the below string in capturing group 1.

```
1. a.
2. b.
3. c.
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oxnrsY/1)

Comment: Most likely they want to capture the Literature part in a group, and the choices in a group, they do not want to capture newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with a capture group:

```sh
r'\(1\)\s+Literature\s+((?:.+\n)+)'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KI5VIE/1)

**Explanation:**

- `\(1\)`: Match `(1)` text
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `Literature`:
- `\s+`:
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(?:.+\n)+`: Match a line with 1+ character followed by newline. Repeat this 1 or more times to allow it to match multiple such lines
- `)`: End capture group #1

Answer (score 0):

Regex for capturing the generic question with that structure:

`\(\d+\)\s+(\w+)\s+((?:\d+\.\s.+\n)+)`

It will capture the title "Literature", then the choices in another group (for a total of 2 groups).

It is not possible to capture repeating groups, so in order to get each of your "1. a." in a separate group you would have to match the second group from above again, with this pattern:

`((\d+\.\s+.+)\n)+)` then globally match to get all groups.